# Rails Fetching objects based on join model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

How would I lookup an object based on a join model attribute? Given the following:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :renters, :through => :libraries
end

class Renter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :books, :through => :libraries
end

class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :renter
  belongs_to :book

  # model has a location:integer property
end
```

How might I search using the following pseudo-code:

```
locations = [1,2]
@all_books = Book.where(:location => locations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the two tables.  Try:

```
locations = [1,2]
@all_books = Book.joins(:libraries).where(libraries: { :location => locations })
```

This joins `books` and `libraries` and filters the records with `libraries.location in(1,2)` condition.

Comment: This works great - looks like it has made my calls much more efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

```
locations = [1,2]
@all_books = Book.joins(:libraries).where("libraries.location in (?)", locations).uniq
```

I am using `uniq` because you will get mutiple records for the same book when you are joining with a `has_many` relation

Comment: Oh this is interesting, so you can do sql like queries as well?